# Intuition behind the formula of total differential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Formula of total differential: $dy(x_1, ..., x_n) = $${\partial f\over\partial x_1}dx_1+\cdots+{\partial f\over\partial x_n}dx_n$

I can not understand why there are specifically addition of ${\partial f\over\partial x_m}dx_m$ monomials, not say, subtraction or multiplication

Comment: The total differential is giving you the linear approximation of $y$ at each point: $y(x)=y(x_0)+y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ plus a higher order correction. That form is what "linear" means in $n$ dimensions. The differentiable functions are just those that admit such an approximation. If you don't see why we would want linear approximation in $n$ dimensions, take a break from calculus/analysis and read up on linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much does $f$ change as its input changes from $x$ to $x + \Delta x$?

You can move from $x$ to $x + \Delta x$ by the following sequence of steps.  (I'll assume $n = 3$ for simplicity.)

1. Move from $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3)$.
2. Move from $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2 + \Delta x_2,x_3)$.
3. Move from $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2 + \Delta x_2,x_3)$ to $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2 + \Delta x_2,x_3 + \Delta x_3)$.

Now let's estimate how much $f$ changes at each step, assuming that $\Delta x$ is very small.

1. The change is approximately $D_1 f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \Delta x_1$.
2. The change is approximately $D_2 f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) \Delta x_2$.
3. The change is approximately $D_3 f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2 + \Delta x_2,x_3) \Delta x_3$.

If we now make the approximation that
$$
D_2 f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) \approx D_2 f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
$$
and 
$$
D_3 f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2 + \Delta x_2,x_3) \approx D_3 f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
$$
then we obtain
$$
\Delta f \approx
D_1 f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \Delta x_1 + D_2 f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \Delta x_2 +
D_3 f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \Delta x_3.
$$

**Edit 1:** Here is some more detail about how I estimated the change in $f$ at step 1.  The partial derivative $D_1 f(x)$ is defined by
$$
D_1 f(x) = \lim_{\Delta x_1 \to 0} \frac{f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) - f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\Delta x_1}.
$$
It follows that
$$
D_1 f(x) \approx \frac{f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) - f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\Delta x_1}
$$
when $\Delta x_1$ is close to $0$.
And from this it follows that
$$
f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) \approx f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
+ D_1 f(x) \Delta x_1
$$
when $x_1$ is close to $0$.
(This statement is one of the key pieces of intuition behind calculus,
and is worth internalizing.)
In other words, when the input to $f$
changes from $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$
to $(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3)$,
the value of $f$ changes
by approximately
$D_1 f(x) \Delta x_1$.

Comment: "then we obtain..."  why there is addition in the last equation? also, why not chage to zeros variables delta x1,... from last equation just as you did in previous equation?

Comment: In the last equation (after "then we obtain") we are summing up the changes in the value of $f$ at each of the three steps.  That's why there is addition.

Comment: " why not chage to zeros variables delta x1,... from last equation just as you did in previous equation?" If we did this, we would end up with the approximation $f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x)$, which is not a very good approximation.

Comment: "...which is not a very good approximation..." $$
D_2 f(x_1 + \Delta x_1,x_2,x_3) \approx D_2 f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
$$ - is this approximation good?

Comment: "is this approximation good?" It's good enough!  At least, if we assume $f$ is continuously differentiable at $x$, it's good enough.  I am only providing intuition here. I suppose that whether or not these approximations are really good enough is determined by whether or not the intuition can be translated into rigorous proofs, and in this case I think the answer turns out to be yes.

Comment: what if delta x_1 == 1000000000000000000000000000????

Comment: Well, the approximation is only good when $\Delta x_1$ is close to $0$.  Maybe I should have emphasized that more clearly.  I'm only providing some intuition here, not trying to be rigorous.

Comment: you confused me even more

Comment: I still do not understand why there is addition

Comment: Haha maybe somebody else will provide a more clear answer.  But maybe it would help if we think of $f$ as telling us the temperature at each point in space.  If I move from point A to be point B, then from point B to point C, then from point C to point D, and the temperature changes by .3 degrees in the first step, -.5 degrees in the second step, and .4 degrees in the third step, then the total change in the temperature when I move from point A to point D is obtained by adding up the individual changes: .3 + -.5 + .4 = .2 degrees is the total change in the value of $f$.

Comment: why do not move directly from point A to point D?

Comment: "why do not move directly from point A to point D?" You could do that, but it might not help explain where this formula comes from. I imagine the individual steps in order to provide some meaning to each term in the summation.

Comment: I think I understood something. I just thought that this formula is accurate for any delta x. but now I grasp from your answers that formula of total differential is not precise. it only works for very little delta xs and it is only approximated to the true value. am I right? and is there some precise formula, which can tell a true value of delta f, is some x changes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, this formula only tells us approximately the change in the value of $f$, and the approximation is only good when $\Delta x$ is very small. A more accurate approximation could be obtained by using quadratic or cubic terms, etc.